# Why did Mike hit Walt when he asked for Mike's help in killing Fring?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I am referring to the bar scene where Walt asks just to be given access to Fring and Walt would do the actual shooting (or whatever). I initially thought Mike was trying to show Walt just how dangerous it was to even consider it or at least Mike sure did not want to be involved with something so dangerous and resent Walt trying to involve him.

But I also saw in other episodes (some in *Better Call Saul*) that Mike is a man of his word, gives money back when he did not have to (as when he got Tuco out of jail and refunded Nacho), and Fring has helped him in major ways -- could it be that Mike was genuinely loyal to Fring and Walt was lucky the Mike did not tell Fring what Walt said. (I assume he did not, he does not seem like a tattler.)

Comment: Please provide more context. "I am referring to the bar scene" is not enough, at the very least provide the episode number (and title), and paint as complete a picture of the situation as possible. Also: please construct your question better. Don't use the title as the first sentence. The title is the title and thus apart; I would at least expect to see it or a similarly worded phrase in the body of your question. People should be able to read your question and figure out what you are asking without even looking at the title. (Look at virtually every other question on this site as an example.)

Answer (score 3):

I understood it to be Mike's way of saying "just who do you think you are?". He later lambasts Walt, after everything falls apart (Season 5, Episode 7):

> "We had a good thing, you stupid son of a bitch! We had Fring, we had a lab, we had everything we needed, and it all ran like clockwork! You could have shut your mouth, cooked, and made as much money as you ever needed! It was perfect! But no! You just had to blow it up! You, and your pride and your ego! You just had to be the man! If you’d done your job and known your place, we’d all be fine right now!"

Mike can see Walt's ego is starting to ruin everything, and he tries to put him in his place.

Comment: It's his way of saying "Who do you think you are?" in a world where mistakes can cause not just your death but that of your family and it just occurs to me that that is why Mike was so violent: Walt was being foolish/incautious in a way that could have resulted in something bad happening to Mike's grand daughter, the entire reason he was involved -- even if it was only Mike getting killed, it wd mean he could no longer help her.